# How to retrieve data of one item in ListView and open another ListView

Tags: php, android, foreign-keys

I am doing an android application that display list of patients in listview. When i click an item in the list another list will display which is the list prescriptions. my problem is how will i retrieve all list of prescription for that particular patient only.

First, click one of this patient in listview

[image]

patient table structure

[image]

then go to next listview for prescription

This is my prescription table structure

[image]

and i want to display this in listview

[image]

this is the relational view for fkey

[image]

Here is my Code for lists of Prescriptions.

```
public class DocListPrescription extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
   TextView docusername;
    Button btndelete;

    String uid;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser2 jParser = new JSONParser2();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> patientsList;

    // url to get all products list
   // private static String url_all_patients = "http://192.168.43.6/android_connect/get_all_patients.php";
    private static String url_all_patients = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_prescriptions.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRESCRIPTION = "prescription";
    private static final String TAG_PRES_ID = "pres_id";
    private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "pres_name";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_DOCUSERNAME = "docusername";

    private ListView lv1;
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray patients = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listpatient);
        //docusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.docusername);

            Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        uid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_UID);


        // Hashmap for ListView
        patientsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();


        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pres_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pres_id)).getText()
                        .toString();


                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddPrescription.class);

                // sending id to next activity
                //in.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME,docusername.getText().toString());

                in.putExtra(TAG_PRES_ID, pres_id);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                //startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(lv1);



    }
    /*
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      if (v.getId()==R.id.list) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(Countries[info.position]);
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.menu.menu);
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
          menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
      }
    }
 */

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        //userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DocMenuActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(TAG_DOCUSERNAME,docusername.getText().toString());
        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //startActivity(dashboard);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DocListPrescription.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading precriptions. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_patients, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Prescriptions: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    patients = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRESCRIPTION);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < patients.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = patients.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PRES_ID);
                        String details = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PRES_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, details);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        patientsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AddPrescription.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            DocListPrescription.this, patientsList,
                            R.layout.rowprescrip, new String[] { TAG_PRES_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pres_id, R.id.pres_name });

      /*


        */           
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });



        }

    }

}
```

From this code. I passed the uid of patient from ListofPatients to this activity so that i will get the uid of that particular item(patient).

Here is my PHP to retrieve all prescriptions for that patient

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM prescription") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["prescription"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $prescription = array();
        $prescription["pres_id"] = $row["pres_id"];
        $prescription["pres_name"] = $row["pres_name"];
       // $prescription["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $prescription["date"] = $row["date"];



        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["prescription"], $prescription);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

From this code. I dont know how to retrieve that prescription using the foreign_key of patient uid. Please help. How can i do this? Thanks in advance. I really need help now.

Comment: It will be better, if you show the table structures along with the mapping tables & what is desired result so we can try taking a look

Comment: @AkhilSidharth i already updated my question. please check and please help me at your best. I'm really in need of this application.

Comment: could you put the patient table structure also along with what is your desired result ? tell, how you want the result to be ?

Comment: ok this is what i want to happen. When you click an item in patientlist it will go to next listview which is the list of prescription for this selected patient. @AkhilSidharth. i updated it now check

Comment: do u get what i want to happen? can u help me now? I posted a lot.

Comment: Cant you select that with simple where clause ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47528/discussion-between-akhil-sidharth-and-user3226149)

Answer (score 0):

Since, your requirement is just to get data of a specific patient from prescription table, use the below code.

```
select * from prescription where patient_user_fkey= mysql_real_escape_string($patient_id);
```

If you want patient details along with it, you can use JOIN to get the data. I am still not sure this is your requirement ? if it is not, atleast let us know what should be your desired output be